# How to import interface from lower level of Solidity?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, interfaces, compilation

I'm extending a large codebase with another contract and I need to import an interface.  My new contract uses `0.8.9` but the rest of the codebase is in `0.6.12`. I'm using Hardhat multi compile to do this

**Interface**

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

interface ISomething { ... }
```

**Implementation**

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

contract Something is ISomething { ... }
```

**New Addition**

```
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract NewThing {
  ISomething public something;
}
```

I can't get this to compile with the interface file shared between them. I could copy it in `0.8.9`, but that seems like bad practice.